# UIPageViewController with Custom UISubview- not receiving touches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I have a Page-Based application, with Custom UIView added as a subview (separate nibs and class). The subview has a button. The subview is on the topmost layer of views but then whenever I click the button, it's not receiving the touches.
I tried bringing the subview to front but it's not working.

```
// swipeable view
self.swipeView.frame = CGRectMake(171, 747, self.swipeView.frame.size.width, self.swipeView.frame.size.height);
OverlayVC *overlayVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"overlayVC"];
overlayVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(171, 747, self.swipeView.frame.size.width, self.swipeView.frame.size.height);

self.swipeView = overlayVC.view;
[self.view addSubview:self.swipeView];
```

The background (blue) is my page view controller and the pink one is the custom uiview added as a subview with button. Button 1 is unlickable
[image]

Comment: where you are adding button means in which view?

Comment: Maybe you forgot simple swipeView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; ?

Comment: @Sunny the subview. There's a button in my subview (the custom view nib). I'm not able to touch the button.

Comment: subview.userInteractionEnabled = YES; give like this.

Comment: @George I already did, but it's not working still.

Comment: I think you need to share more code because you shared setting frames code, not recieving touches, not creating view's

Comment: @Sunny- I tried that already. It seems like my button and other view can't be tapped. Im sure though that the view is on the topmost layer.

Comment: I included an image, the 'button 1' is unclickable.